# monitor displays shows no picture in display settings and goes black randomly

Tags: macos, display, thunderbolt, hdmi

This is my first question so please pardon my mistakes.
I use a Mid 2017 MacBook Pro with a HP V270 Monitor. The monitor connects fine using a USB-C to HDMI cable but the issue I'm having currently is that my monitor randomly goes off and then comes back on after few seconds. IT seems to be a connection issue but I'm not sure how to verify that but an odd that I noticed in the settings is that there isn't a picture on the monitor [image: display settings] but my MacBook screen displays a picture. Please do not confuse the picture I'm referring to with the on the hardware screen. Hardware screen shows a picture but goes off randomly. The screen in the picture above remains black no matter how I tweaked the settings beside it. Also I'm currently running the Catalina beta but I do not think the issue is from the beta because I've seen other users experience same issues.

MacBook Pro Mid 2017. 4 USB-C Ports and I've connected with both my lid open and closed(using an app called InsomniaX). I'm also using a direct cable from my USB-C port to HDMI.

Comment: The 'black screen' icon in the prefs pane is default. Mine shows the exact same icon for 2 perfectly-working external monitors.

Comment: I've added an answer, but it'd be good if you could [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/366342/edit) your question to clarify which model MBP you have (i.e. 13" v 15", and if 13" how many USB-C ports)? Also, are you connected to the external display in closed-clamshell mode (i.e. with your MBP lid closed), or are you trying to use both the internal and external display simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your cable is connected securely at both ends, the first thing to try is connecting the HP V270 display to a different USB-C port to see what difference, if any, this makes.

If this has no effect then I'd reset your NVRAM.

**Resetting the NVRAM**

Your Mac uses Non-Volatile Random-Access Memory (NVRAM). To reset the NVRAM on your MacBook Pro model follow these steps:

1. **Shut down your machine.** Yes, a full shut down, so go to Apple > Shut Down so you’re not just logging out.
2. Press the <kbd>power button</kbd> (in your case this is the Touch ID button) *and then* immediately press the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> keys.
3. Keep these keys pressed down for **at least 20 seconds!**
4. Let go of the keys and let your Mac reboot normally.

**Note:** When you log back in you ***may*** need to readjust some of your system preferences (e.g. speaker volume, screen resolution, startup disk selection, time zone information, etc).

If you still have problems after doing this, let me know.

---

Since resetting the NVRAM and swapping the ports has had no real impact, I'd strongly recommend testing your display with another computer and/or trying a different cable.

In terms of the MacBook Pro itself, you could use **Apple Diagnostics** to test its hardware for some peace of mind. You can do this as follows:

1. Fully shut down your MBP
2. Restart your MBP
3. Immediately press the <kbd>D</kbd> key and **keep it down** until you see the Diagnostics screen appear
4. Wait for Diagnostics to finish (this typically only takes a few minutes)
5. Once complete, one of two things will appear on the screen:

   - a *No issues found* message
   - a brief description of any errors found plus further instructions
6. If the diagnostics test does find errors, take a note of what they are

**Note:** If pressing and holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key at Step 3 doesn't work, start again at Step 1 and, at Step 3 press and hold both the <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> keys instead. This will try and run diagnostics from the internet instead, so you will need to allow more time for it to complete.

Comment: I set my volume to a particular point and also changed my timezone. I tried resetting the nvram several times and I come back to meet same settings. I'm confused on how to do this because I followed the instructions carefully. I just tested it by watching a movie and it just occurred after like 40 minutes.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that you're not sure if you're resetting the NVRAM properly? Or...?

Comment: I'm following the instructions carefully and I've tried about 10 more times. I ran `csrutil disable` in recovery mode and I tried clearing it but I'm getting `nvram: Error clearing firmware variables: (iokit/common) not permitted` not sure if that error log helps..

Comment: I should have asked, do you have a firmware password enabled on your MBP? Also, are you using the built-in keyboard or an external keyboard? And just to clarify your first comment above, what you're saying is that after trying to reset the NVRAM your timezone and sound volume remains unchanged?

Comment: I do not have a firmware password and I'm using a built-in keyboard. Yes, my volume and timezone remained unchanged and I also wasn't asked to select startup disk(I read somewhere that clearing nvram would cause this)

Comment: Ok, we'll tackle the whole NVRAM issue first (i.e. we need to know for sure it's been reset). Firstly, resetting the NVRAM won't definitely change your Startup Disk, timezone info, etc - it's a case of it *may* change these. However, the most reliable tell-tale is usually the sound volume, so I would mute your sound and then  try resetting the NVRAM again. If the sound volume is no longer mute upon restarting, you'll know that NVRAM has been reset. Also, the reason at Step 3 I've stated to keep those keys down for 20 seconds is to make sure your MBP has had time to start a second reboot. So...

Comment: ...another tell-tale sign in your case would be keeping an eye on the screen and when you see the Apple logo appear and disappear a second time, then let go of the keys and let your MBP reboot normally. In other words, keep your keys down until you've seen the Apple logo appear/disappear twice.

Comment: I've tried resetting the nvram with my volume set a different positions(including mute). I usually hold it for 20 seconds and I make sure it's accurate by using a stopwatch immediately I press the keys. My laptop reboots twice and sometimes If I don't let go of the keys quickly, it reboots thrice.

Comment: In that case it sounds like you're resetting the NVRAM okay. Are you still having issues with the external monitor randomly switching off and on? If so, have you tried connecting it to a different port on your MBP?

Comment: I usually use the left side ports. I've tired the right side once, it restarted and I just gave up and plugged the HDMI back into the left side. I used it today and it didn't go off until like 2 hours. I was watching a movie in my browser and not doing any processor intensive task, normally I'd be programming with the computer.

Comment: I just noticed my MacBook keyboard's light is flickering. I forgot to mention I tried clearing my SMC earlier but after my computer restarted, my fan was at high speed and I fixed it by following the SMC clearing process again. Before I cleared my SMC the second time, I tried the NVRAM clear process and it didn't fix that.

Comment: It sounds like you've reset both the NVRAM and SMC, so no need to do that again - at least not for this issue. In case you missed it, I did add more to my answer yesterday. I'd recommend you doing all those when you get a chance because it's either not related to the MBP itself (i.e. it's the cable or the monitor) or it's an actual problem with the MBP which means you should run Apple Diagnostics and, for good measure, if you have another display you can access, also testing it with that. Note: Testing another cable doesn't mean it has to be to HDMI, it could be to DVI or VGA for this monitor.

Comment: I ran Apple Diagnostics and it found no issues. The issue still occurs but not as frequent as before.

Comment: Yeah, to be honest, I didn't think it was any sort of fault with your MBP. These things are often related to some sort of weird conflict/incompatibility related to the hardware and/or cables involved. It really would be good to test with a different cable, either another USB-C > HDMI or maybe a USB-C > DVI, but of course that's easier said then done. I suppose it gets down to how frequently/annoying it is for you? And there's always contacting HP to see if they have any suggestions re that model.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance throughout the process.